# How to prevent Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey from making incorrectly ordered permissions?

Tags: c#, permissions

When i try to run this code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(@"Software\ATestKey");
}
```

It creates the key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ATestKey. I'm running 32 bit code on a 64 bit Windows 8.1 machine. The project is a Any CPU project. VS 2013 is running as administrator.

When I use regedit to look at the permissions of this key it gives me a warning:

"The permissions on ATestKey are incorrectly ordered, which may cause some entries to be ineffective."

I have seen more questions about this problem, but as far as I can tell they all "inherited" a wrong set of permissions to start with. This is a clean new key.
The permissions of HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node are OK.

Is there a better way to create this key?

Comment: The code is fine. The problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you, sorry for the late reaction. I was expecting an email with a notification.
You must be right, there can't be anything wrong with so little code :-).
I tested it using Delphi, that gave the same problems. It must be my computer I guess.